# Unable to reference Hibernate 3.2.5.ga javadocs within NetBeans 6.8

Tags: hibernate, javadoc, netbeans6.8

How can I make the Hibernate javadocs available within the NetBeans coding window.

I have followed these steps so far and the javadoc fails to appear

Select Tools\Libraries
Select Hibernate
Select the Javadoc tab
Select the Add ZIP/Folder button
Selected the jar file

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with NB 7.0.1/hibernate 3.6.7:

1. Downloaded hibernate from http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3
2. Unpacked the file
3. Tools=>Libraries=>New Library...
4. In classpath tab added jars
5. In Javadoc tab: Add Zip/folder: *unpack_dir*/documentation/javadocs